# wpf binding from child window

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, binding, childwindow

I'm learning XAML and I'm having a problem binding content of a control to a settings property from a child window.

Here's a quick example I've made to make it more clear. Calling the child from the main window:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim OwndWindow As New WindowChild
    OwndWindow.Owner = Me
    OwndWindow.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

And this is the child:

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WindowChild"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="WindowChild" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ObjDatPro" ObjectType="{x:Type src:TestSettings}"></ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ObjDatPro}}">
        <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  IsChecked="{Binding Default.BoolSetting, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

At this point Visual Studio is reporting an error: *The name "TestSettings" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApplication2".* (Line 7, Column 49)

I've tried changing this part to `WindowChild.TestSettings`, but then VS complains that nested types are not supported.

Changing CLR namespace to `WpfApplication2.WindowChild` or even `WindowChild` doesn't do the trick, VS says: *Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'WindowChild' that could not be found.*

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try this: xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2;assembly=WpfApplication2". If it doesn't help clean the Solution and Rebuild everything.

Comment: I've finally figured it out: instead of using `<Window.Resources>` and `ObjectDataProvider` all it needed was `<Window.DataContext><src:TestSettings/></Window.DataContext>`.

Comment: Since you figured it out yourself, you should write your own answer and mark this as answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696669/wpf-binding-from-child-window#comment22306429_15696669):

> I've finally figured it out: instead of using `<Window.Resources>` and `ObjectDataProvider` all it needed was `<Window.DataContext><src:TestSettings/></Window.DataContext>`.